# How do I access a public property of a User Control from codebehind?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a user control in a repeater that I need to pass data to during the databound event, so I've created two public properties in the control. How do I access these properties from the page's codebehind class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

During the databind event in the repeater?

```
MyUserControl myControl = (MyUserControl)e.item.FindControl("NameInASPX");
myControl.MyCustomProperty = foo;
```

Comment: Where does the MyUserControl type come from? In my case it doesn't exist.

Comment: For whatever reason, Visual Studio wasn't aware of the type of my user control before, and now it is. VS's IDE magic can be very fickle sometimes.